# How to get start and end point of lines in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a network as GeoDataFrame with columns node1, node2 and geometry. I also have a polygon geometry, which borders the area to look at. I need another GeoDataFrame containing all distinct nodes in the area.

Using gdf.apply to get the point geometries is not very fast. Is there a more performant solution? This is the snippet I have:

```
# get start and end point from linestring
def endpoints(row):
    p = get_parts(row.geom.boundary)
    return dict(node1=p[0], node2=p[1])

# this needs time
df_netw[['geom1', 'geom2']] = df_netw.apply(endpoints, axis=1, result_type='expand')

# create node table and choose nodes in my_area
df_nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
                dict(
                    node=pd.concat((df_netw.node1, df_netw.node2))),
                geometry=pd.concat((df_netw.geom1, df_netw.geom2)),
                crs=25832) \
           .drop_duplicates()
df_nodes = df_nodes[df_nodes.intersects(my_area)] \
                .set_index('node', drop=False) \
                .sort_index()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply will loop in python over all geometries, which makes it slow for large geodataframes.

When you use geopandas or shapely functions on a geoseries, they will loop in the lower level programming language C that is way faster. For what you want to accomplish you could par example use [shapely.get_point](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.get_point.html#shapely.get_point).

Sample script:

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

line1 = shapely.LineString([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)])
line2 = shapely.LineString([(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2], crs=4326)
gdf["geom1"] = shapely.get_point(gdf.geometry, 0)
gdf["geom2"] = shapely.get_point(gdf.geometry, -1)

print(gdf[["geom1", "geom2"]])
```

Output:

```
                     geom1                    geom2
0  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)  POINT (2.00000 0.00000)
1  POINT (0.00000 1.00000)  POINT (2.00000 1.00000)
```

Comment: Oh that's great. I didn't know or expect shapely functions to work with arrays of geometries.